# Phone number regex C# with hyphen

Tags: c#, regex

I need to validate a phone number in C#.

The pattern should contain 10 digits (mandatory) and `-` can be used anywhere in the pattern.

- eg 1: `9876543210`
- eg 2: `98-765-432-10`
- eg 3: `-98-765-432-10-`

This is what I tried:

```
Regex a = new Regex(@"^([0-9]{10}\-*)$")
```

Comment: you mean exact 10 digits?

Comment: The pattern should contain 10 digits and may or may not contain hyphen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below regex to check if the input has exactly 10 digits or not.

```
^(?:-*\d-*){10}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dN8sA5/5)

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use the exact validate 10 digit phone number (not more, not less), you can use this Regex

```
string pattern = "([\-]?\d[\-]?){10}";
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
string num = "98-765-432-10";  // any number
if(Regex.IsMatch(num, "^[0-9-]+$") && num.Replace("-","").Length == 10){
  // do something
}
```

In the above, you check if the number contains only hyphens and number and then checks if the length of the digits is 10. It also uses short circuiting, which is better.

I'm not sure of the syntax, but it must be it.